# How to display current time in a tooltip flot chart?

Tags: jquery, time, tooltip, flot

Sorry if this problem has been already questioned. I think I'm close to what I wanna do, but it's something I omit.

I have a real time flot chart which has on x-axis the current time (HH:mm:ss) and on y-axis a random value. I want to display in a tooltip the value y and the current time.

I managed to display a time (which doesn't correspond to current time) and the random value. My question is how could I display the actual current time?

Here is my code:

```
xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                tickSize: [2, "second"],
                tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                    var date = new Date(v);

                    if (date.getSeconds() % 5 == 0) {
                        var hours = date.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + date.getHours() : date.getHours();
                        var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
                        var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();

                        var w = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

                        return w;
                    } else {
                        return "";
                    }
                },
                axisLabel: "Time",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 10
            },

yaxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                tickSize: 5,
                tickFormatter: function (v, axis) {
                    if (v % 10 == 0) {
                        return v + "%";
                    } else {
                        return "";
                    }
                },
                axisLabel: "CPU loading",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 6
            },
```

and now tooltip display:

```
   $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {

    if ($("#enablePosition:checked").length > 0) {
        var str = "(" + pos.x.toFixed(2) + ", " + pos.y.toFixed(2) + ")";
        $("#hoverdata").text(str);
    }

    if ($("#enableTooltip:checked").length > 0) {
        if (item) {
            var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
            ygb = x;


            var date = new Date(x * 1000);
            // Hours part from the timestamp
            var hours = date.getHours();
            // Minutes part from the timestamp
            var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
            // Seconds part from the timestamp
            var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

            // Will display time in 10:30:23 format
            var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);

            $("#tooltip").html("At hour " + formattedTime + " " + item.series.label + " is " + y)
                .css({ top: item.pageY + 5, left: item.pageX + 5 })
                .fadeIn(200);
        } else {
            $("#tooltip").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

Hope I made myself understood. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows the problem?

Comment: Actually I can't because it is a part of a bigger program. I managed to store in an array the current time (HH:mm:ss) from x-axis and to display it on the tooltip. The problem I'm facing now is how to display only the current time, and not the entire array, corresponding to the hovered part of chart.

Comment: Then we have to guess somewhat ... comparing the formatting of the time values in the x axis ticks and the tooltip, you multiply by 1000 in the tooltip (`var date = new Date(x * 1000);`). Try removing that.

Comment: This part is now commented:
var date = new Date(x * 1000);
          // Hours part from the timestamp
            var hours = date.getHours();
          // Minutes part from the timestamp
            var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
          // Seconds part from the timestamp
            var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

Well I made some changes since I posted the code. What I changed is: I created an array var vect=[]; and then I stored in it the current time (that var w)  vect.push(w);. At the end I sad that var x =vect; and displayed x. Hope you understand the changes I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to display on tooltip the x-axis'current time. Maybe someone needs to do the same. The first code part doesn't change. The second part is like:

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {

            if ($("#enablePosition:checked").length > 0) {
                var str = "(" + pos.x.toFixed(2) + ", " + pos.y.toFixed(2) + ")";

            }

            if ($("#enableTooltip:checked").length > 0) {
                if (item) {
                    var x = parseInt(item.datapoint[0]);
                    var y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

                    //Formating from UNIX timestamp to "HH:mm:ss"
                    //To do so you also must to include moment.js library
                    var timestamp = moment(x).format("HH:mm:ss");
                   //Display tooltip:
                    $("#tooltip").html("At hour " + timestamp + " " + item.series.label + " is " + y)
                        .css({ top: item.pageY + 5, left: item.pageX + 5 })
                        .fadeIn(200);
                } else {
                    $("#tooltip").hide();
                }
            }
        });

        $("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
            if (item) {
                $("#clickdata").text(" - click point " + item.dataIndex + " in " + item.series.label);
                plot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
            }
        });
```